# Gitlab runner throws errors (kern.log) on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm running a gitlab instance (9.2.1) on my ubuntu server (16.04 LTS) as a docker container.
Today I looked at my kern.log file and there are endless entries like this:

```
Sep 24 07:13:06 user gitlab-runner[18242]: time="2017-09-24T07:13:06+02:00" level=error msg="Checking for jobs... forbidden" runner=48aab051 #012<nil>
Sep 24 07:13:06 user gitlab-runner[18242]: time="2017-09-24T07:13:06+02:00" level=warning msg="Checking for jobs... failed" runner=4ad89567 status="couldn't execute POST against https://ci.server.com/ap$
Sep 24 07:13:06 user gitlab-runner[18242]: time="2017-09-24T07:13:06+02:00" level=error msg="Checking GitLab compatibility... not-compatible" reason="GitLab Runner >= 9.0 can be used ONLY with GitLab $
```

I do not understand these messages, so I need some help to get them interpreted to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I met once lines similar to your third line. They meant that the version of the CI runner I was running was not compatible with the version of the Gitlab Omnibus installation it was trying to contact. I solved the problem by updating the Gitlab Omnibus installation to the most recent version.

Line two seems to mean that the runner pooled the server to see if any job was available, but it failed to contact the server: this should be further investigated, but problably is related to the version mismatch which is probably causing lines like the third one.

The first line I don't know for sure, but it seems that the runner got a "Forbidden" answer from the Gitlab Omnibus installation. Do you have some form of authentication in place?

Comment: Thanks for that input. I don't use omnibus. Gitlab is running as a docker container...

Comment: I think that the issues can be similar, given that (as I was expecting and as shown by the [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/~/dockerfile/) of the Gitlab-ce image) the Docker image of gitlab is just an Omnibus installation inside a docker image. Now to the possible causes for the failed post requests etc you have to add a Docker misconfiguration. Try updating the image to the lastest version and see if the issues persists